# Variation of Intensity when a source moves

Tags: acoustics, doppler-effect, intensity

When a sound source moves, frequency perceived by the observer is changed due to the doppler shift. Does this apply to intensity too? If yes then how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Intensity of a sound wave is proportional to it’s frequency squared (among other variables). If a source of sound is moving, the frequency and therefore intensity of the sound will increase or decrease as measured by the observer.